# How to override the title of JQuery mobile Datebox?

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I am developing a Japanese mobile site using Datebox calendar. I managed to override most of the date format and labels, but I'm not sure how to modify the title which shows the Month and Year. Instead of showing 6月2013, I want it to show 2013年6月. The two characters basically represent year and month.

I'm using Datebox version 1, and I have overriden the dateFormat and headerFormat as listed below. What am I missing here?

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox1/demos/api/matrix.html#matrix&ui-page=0-0

[image: Datebox version 1 screenshot]

Comment: why are not using version2 of datebox, any specific reasons?

Comment: The technology has been decided before 2.0 was launched, and I does 2.0 make a difference?

Comment: not at all, just some new features are added and v2 is their for you but talking about your question have you created any code for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "created any code for this"?

Comment: have you tried something to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time since I played with v1.  But...

1. Think about upgrading the v2.  Language files stay the same, but v2 is way, way more stable.
2. You have a couple options for headerFormat -

   a. you can either mess with it in the language file (which I assume you are loading, judging by the fact that english is the default).

   b. Override options..headerFormat.

   c. It *looks* like just setting options.headerFormat is supposed to override it too...  ymmv.  Like I said, it's been a while.
3. The bad news:  It is *possible* that the calendar mode of v1 does not in fact use headerFormat - if that is the case, look for this line, around about 1421, which looks suspiciously hard-coded to me.  Which means you'll need to edit the sources directly.  Sorry about that.

```js
self.controlsInput.empty().html(o.lang[o.useLang].monthsOfYear[self.theDate.getMonth()] + " " + self.theDate.getFullYear());
```

Finally, if you do decide to upgrade to v2, <strike>it looks like it is *also* hardcoded - line 160.  I'll work on making this an option instead.</strike> **Edit**: the option you are looking for in v2 is `overrideCalHeaderFormat` / `calHeaderFormat`.